# Link not Behaving as Expected When Linking to a Specific Part of a Web Page

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I'm trying to link to a specific part of a page. I've added the `href="#disclaimer"` attribute to the anchor link I wish to go to, and on the actual link to be clicked I've done the href link attribute as `href="./terms-conditions.php/#disclaimer"`

The site is a static site currently being hosted on a localhost MAMP server, but I don't understand why the link isn't working. It does go to the correct page, but doesn't go directly to the `#disclaimer` href link at the bottom of this page, and the page is all broken without any styles. When I visit the page normally via the main nav menu the page all works fine.

I'm very confused — and any help would be awesome.

Emily

```html
<!-- Code with link to click -->

<p>Copyright © 2019 All rights reserved. <a title="disclaimer" href="./terms-conditions.php/#disclaimer">Disclaimer.</a> Authorised and regulated by the Solicitors Regulation Authority of England and Wales with registered number xxxxxx.</p>

<!-- Code code on the page you arrive at -->

<h3><a class="td" href="#disclaimer">Disclaimer</a></h3>
<p>The information you obtain at this site is not, nor is it intended to be, legal advice. You should consult a solicitor for advice regarding your individual situation. We invite you to contact us and welcome your calls, letters and electronic mail. Contacting us does not create a solicitor-client relationship. Please do not send any confidential information to us until such time as a solicitor-client relationship has been established.</p>
```

Comment: Could you please post your code - particularly the href section & the #disclaimer section. But all would be best

Comment: Hi @EGC I've added the code as requested

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need!

(Ignore the giant div, it is to indicate that it goes to the correct position) :)

```html
  <p>Copyright © 2019 All rights reserved. <a title="disclaimer" 
  href="#disclaimer">Disclaimer.</a> Authorised and regulated by the 
  Solicitors Regulation Authority of England and Wales with registered 
  number 
  xxxxxx.</p>

    <!-- Spacer content -->
    <div style="height: 4000px">
    
    </div>

    <!-- Code code on the page you arrive at -->
    <h3><a class="td" id="disclaimer">Disclaimer</a></h3>
    <p>The information you obtain at this site is not, nor is it intended to be, legal advice. You should consult a solicitor for advice regarding your individual situation. We invite you to contact us and welcome your calls, letters and electronic mail. Contacting us does not create a solicitor-client relationship. Please do not send any confidential information to us until such time as a solicitor-client relationship has been established.</p>
```

So, the reason this works?

The '#' tag operates as a [page anchor](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/guides/html_links/), where it looks for an associated 'id' tag, and navigates to it. As a result, on click of the anchor tag you "will jump to the appropriate section of the same page" ([ref](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/guides/html_links/))

**To make this work specifically for your site, please use this code:**

```html
<p>Copyright © 2019 All rights reserved. <a title="disclaimer" 
  href="./terms-conditions.php#disclaimer">Disclaimer.</a> Authorised and regulated by the 
  Solicitors Regulation Authority of England and Wales with registered 
  number 
  xxxxxx.</p>

    <!-- Spacer content -->
    <div style="height: 4000px">
    
    </div>

    <!-- Code code on the page you arrive at -->
    <h3><a class="td" id="disclaimer">Disclaimer</a></h3>
    <p>The information you obtain at this site is not, nor is it intended to be, legal advice. You should consult a solicitor for advice regarding your individual situation. We invite you to contact us and welcome your calls, letters and electronic mail. Contacting us does not create a solicitor-client relationship. Please do not send any confidential information to us until such time as a solicitor-client relationship has been established.</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The 'Disclaimer' element it goes to on the site I've done is on a different page. This only works if it is on the same page.

Comment: This line `href="./terms-conditions.php#disclaimer"` as per the final code snippet will allow allow it to redirect to the page `terms-conditions.php` though